# .htaccess rewrite to unmounted folder resource

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, external

Im trying to use a .htaccess file on an apache server to point /cmsfiles/flipbooks/thisFlipBook/ to /thisFlipBook

Ive tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/thisFlipBook/ /cmsfiles/flipbooks/thisFlipBook[L,R=302]
```

as well as:

```
RewriteRule ^/thisFlipBook/cmsfiles/flipbooks/thisFlipBook[L]
```

(without the R tag so that mod_rewrite knows its an internal apache redirect instead of having the browser send a new request for the rewritten resources.)

The first rule results in a 404, and the second results in:

```
/thisFlipBook/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/
```

However if you manually navigate to /cmsfiles/flipbooks/thisFlipBook it manages to find the index.html file and load it successfully.

Am i doing something wrong?

Also: server side apache redirects and unmounted folder are the correct way to be doing this right? Client started requesting so many flipbooks that we've moved them out of the project for deployments sake.

Comment: No one can say anything about that strange 'unmounted folder' issue if you don't explain that detail.

Comment: The endless rewriting loop with the index.php trails appears to be some side effect with the cms also tring to rewrite incoming requests. Most likely that cms redirects `flipbooks/<anything>` to its internal router called `index.php`. Then again your rewriting rule kicks in and rewrites again... An endless loop.

Comment: Oh, and... You need some whitespace between the path and the flags in square brackets. In the example rules you give above there is no such whitespace. I am surprised that you don't get an error...